# Android: GUI: Getting items from listview

Tags: android, user-interface

I am having custom listview(with image, text and check box) and a button(named Done) in my listactivity.

I am able to check/un check check box upon list item click event by implementing listvw.setOnItemClickListener().

Now when i click Done button, I want to know how many list items are checked. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you track that on your `setOnItemClickListener` implementation? Something like this will work:

```
int count = 0;

public void setOnItemClickListener(args...){
    // blah blah blah
    checkbox.setChecked(!checkbox.isChecked());
    // you said: *how many*
    count += checkbox.isChecked() ? 1 : -1;
}
```

In the case above, you just have to use the `count` variable from your click listener of the *Done* `Button`. Of course, this will work fine if all the `Checkboxes` are unchecked when the Activity starts.